# Kafka behaviour if consumer fail

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message-queue

I've looked up throught a lot of different articles about Apache Kafka transactions, recovery and exactly-once new features. Still don't understand an issue with consumer recovery.  How to be sure that every message from queue will be processed even if one of consumers dies?

Let's say we have a topic partition assigned to consumer. Consumer polls a message and started to work on it. And shutted down due to power failure without commit. What will happens? Will any other consumer from the same group repoll this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumers periodically send heartbeats, telling the broker that they are alive. If broker does not receive heartbeats from the consumer, it considers the consumer dead and reassigns its partitions.  So, if consumer dies, its partitions will be assigned to another consumer from the group and uncommitted messages will be sent to the newly assigned consumer.

Comment: «uncommitted messages will be sent to the newly assigned consumer» -- is there an article or documentation that describes such behaviour?

Comment: Yes, for example in [javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html).

Comment: i'm very very sorry for repeating the same question, but where exactly in javadoc said that uncommitted messages will be sent to newly assigned consumer? Can you quote it please?

Comment: It says _On each poll, consumer will try to use the last consumed offset as the starting offset and fetch sequentially. The last consumed offset can be manually set through seek(TopicPartition, long) or automatically set as the last committed offset for the subscribed list of partitions._ So when the consumer receives new partitions from the dead consumer, it starts from the last committed offset.

Comment: But better to quote from [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html): _As a consumer in the group reads messages from the partitions assigned by the coordinator, it must commit the offsets corresponding to the messages it has read. If the consumer crashes or is shutdown, its partitions will be re-assigned to another member, which will begin consumption from the last committed offset of each partition. If the consumer crashes before any offset has been committed, then the consumer which takes over its partitions will use the reset policy._

Comment: Thanks you, Katya!

Comment: How to handle when the committed offsets were kept in memory only and due to a failure committed messages needs to be processed again?